# How to run script in several data frames at once?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 58 data named as: h5, h6,... h64.
I want to run following script on all of them at one time and save the result in 1 
new data file. this is my script:

```
t <- read.table("h5",header = F, row.names=1)
 cor(t)
 (cor(t))^2
lm(t$V3 ~ t$V2, data=t)
```

I know for reading all the data files at once I can use :

```
myFiles <- list.files(pattern="h.*")
```

But for the rest I do not know how to make a loop or how to store the result in a new data frame. any suggestion?

I show in below my input file structure :

```
HO840M3000540481 993.38 1543.1765
HO840M3000540483 -0.51 1120.8224
HO840M3000540497 1192.06 1651.3322
HO840M3004672697 388.5 1140.0917
HO840M3004672704 426.9 836.3676
HO840M3006005895 524.65 1301.8218
HO840M3006972816 1673.99 1389.1919
HO840M3006988837 188.35 385.6415
HO840M3006988891 2987.58 1919.2762
HO840M3006989113 1097.59 1746.4724
HO840M3007701817 1320.5 1058.4915
HO840M3007701858 -372.15 1090.6167
HO840M3007815980 548.58 759.3870
```

Comment: you can either check the total row count first and create an empty data.frame which you fill on each iteration or write/reload to a table with append `write.table(x, file = "", append = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shot in the dark...

```
myFiles <- paste0("h", 5:64)
all <- lapply(myFiles, read.table, header=F, row.names=1)

t1 <- lapply(all, cor)
t2 <- lapply(all, function(x) (cor(x))^2)

all.lm <- lapply(all, function(x)lm(V3 ~ V2, data=x))
```

EDIT: 
I can't reproduce the error mentioned in the comment, based on the data-structure provided. See below for the execution.

Please elaborate on what specific error you are facing.

```
dat <- structure(list(V2 = c(993.38, -0.51, 1192.06, 388.5, 426.9, 524.65, 
1673.99, 188.35, 2987.58, 1097.59, 1320.5, -372.15, 548.58), 
V3 = c(1543.1765, 1120.8224, 1651.3322, 1140.0917, 836.3676, 
1301.8218, 1389.1919, 385.6415, 1919.2762, 1746.4724, 1058.4915, 
1090.6167, 759.387)), .Names = c("V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("HO840M3000540481", 
"HO840M3000540483", "HO840M3000540497", "HO840M3004672697", "HO840M3004672704", 
"HO840M3006005895", "HO840M3006972816", "HO840M3006988837", "HO840M3006988891", 
"HO840M3006989113", "HO840M3007701817", "HO840M3007701858", "HO840M3007815980"
))

all <- list(dat)


lapply(all, cor)


[[1]]
          V2        V3
V2 1.0000000 0.6741098
V3 0.6741098 1.0000000

lapply(all, function(x) (cor(x))^2)

[[1]]
          V2        V3
V2 1.0000000 0.4544241
V3 0.4544241 1.0000000


lapply(all, function(x)lm(V3 ~ V2, data=x))

[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = V3 ~ V2, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           V2  
   943.3531       0.3354
```

Comment: I get this error:Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no lines available in input

Comment: Can't help you without knowing what your data structure is.

Comment: i put a part of data in my explanation to show you how is the data structure. meanwhile I do not have h17 and h33

Comment: thanks, but again the same error:  all <- lapply(myFiles, read.table, header=F, row.names=1)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no lines available in input

Comment: Check your file names with `list.files`. Make sure the file name, path and extension are all correctly stated.

Comment: I checked it with list.files and this is I get : > list.files
function (path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, 
    recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, 
    no.. = FALSE) 
.Internal(list.files(path, pattern, all.files, full.names, recursive, 
    ignore.case, include.dirs, no..))
<bytecode: 0x0000000009d071d0>
<environment: namespace:base>

Comment: what that mean? can you guide me to understand it ? still I can not use your script because oF the same problem. I really appreciate.

Comment: When you type in `list.files` in the R console, it return the syntax of the list.files function. It's like just typing `sum` or `mean` in the console. Instead, run `list.files` as a function, and assign it as an object, e.g. `all.files <- list.files()`. Change the argument of the `list.files`  pattern and working directory to point towards the right file names that are in your directory.

Comment: Also, I wrote a small post on [reading multiple files in R](https://minerva79.github.io/Reading-multiple-files-in-R/) earlier. Contact me again if you're still confused.